# How Can i Validate datatable's Data before inserting it using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I'm importing 3 thousands rows from Excel Sheet using ExcelDataReader to Datatable.

How can i validate these rows before inserting them into database using SqlBulkCopy.Writetoserver().

**Questions:**

**1.** How to compare my datatable to the TableScheme of one of the SQL Server Tables.

**2.** Can i Validate FK Constraints and PK Duplications before insertion

**3.** if i've some table like this with SponsorID Column with FK to the Same Table

**ID - Name - Age - Relation - Column4 - SponsorID**

100 - Adam Michale - 32 - himself  -  1/1/2015 - 100

101 - Anna Mike - 29 - wife  -  1/1/2015 - 100

102 - Sarah Adam - 6 - Daughter -  1/1/2015 - 100

is there anyway to do such insertion using SqlBulkCopy.

**Thanks in advance.**

And I'll be more than happy to hear about any other approaches for insertions like this if there are any

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Comment: ThanksThiago. For question one and two yes it was usfel but I'm didn't understand your answer for number three ... the table you see above is the dbo.table scheme and this ID isIDENTITY .. In my excel I don't have this column nor the SponsorID column .. but I could have a sponsor name for each record or another SponsorID but I don't know how could I use this ID

Comment: I see, you could have something like: select * from SqlTable as table1 inner join SqlTabel as table2 on table1.Name = table2.SponsorName, the problem would be if you have people with same name...=(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can query your excel file and compare that using SQL language. See example below:

   SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
   'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\excel-sql-server.xls', [Sheet1$])

Find more options about Distributed queries on this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306397/en-us).

2. You can query the data that you already have on the sql data and compare it with excel in order to verify PK/entry duplications.
3. You can create a column OldID, with the IDs present on the excel. Then update the Sponsor ID with the new IDs using the OldID reference.